# filling right margin with my table in print

Tags: css, printing, media-queries, printing-web-page, print-css

i have a print using `@media print`. Now, i am having trouble about this, why it doesn't fill my table with it. I set the margin to 0 and also the `@page` margin into 0. Still it doesn't. Also i increase the size of my `table th` still it doesnt occupy the right space which i taked screen shot and i put red shade .

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is my css:

```
@media print{
    .no-print {
      display: none;
    }
    printable {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    body {
      margin: 2mm 5mm 5mm 2mm;
    }
    table th {
      width: 40%;
    }
  }
  @page {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

Comment: any answers or comments please?

Comment: Provide a snippet

Comment: Need to see the HTML. In the CSS, I can't see where you're trying to set the table's width to 100%.